# Will using window.stop(); be bad for search engines?

Tags: javascript, function, seo

Will it hurt my website ? The only reason I ask is because I'm not sure if google wont be able to crawl the page with that function in place..

Also, what this function does is like clicking the (x) button on the browser, that is why I'am a little bit confused..

Comment: Why do you want to use that method?

Comment: Google now crawls pages with JavaScript enabled, so it's possible it'd interfere. Why are you using the function at all? Seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: @Vohuman and ceejayoz I want to stop things from loading if they take too long..

Comment: @FábioLinhares Why don't you fix the fact that they're taking too long?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO, not programming.

Comment: @Pang it's about both!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

window.stop() stops the loading of external assets, but not the document itself. This should not effect google being able to crawl your site, but it probably wont index the images.

Comment: Google's crawler now uses JavaScript (and CSS) to better understand the page. Preventing those assets from loading may be very bad for SEO, particularly in the future. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html

Comment: Im not sure if you downvoted me, but I said nothing about SEO. It should not effect googles ability to crawl your site, but it wont be a positive mark for your SEO

Comment: The title of the question is `Will using window.stop(); be bad for search engines?` and the question asks `Will it hurt my website ?`. IMO, ignoring the potentially major SEO downsides garners a downvote.